# R. summarizing data without merge

Tags: r, dataframe, plyr, summarization

I have a dataframe (df) of goals scored against various teams by date

```
gamedate teamID Gls
 1992-08-22  CHL  3
 1992-08-22  MNU  1
 1992-08-23  ARS  0
 1992-08-23  LIV  2
 1992-08-24  MNU  0
 1992-08-25  LIV  2
 1992-08-26  ARS  0
 1992-08-26  CHL  0
```

I wish to produce a summary table which shows the number of games played and
number of games these teams have blanked the opposition on each date

```
gamedate   games blanks
 1992-08-22   2     0
 1992-08-23   2     1
 1992-08-24   1     1
 1992-08-25   1     0
 1992-08-26   2     2
```

I can get the games and blanks separately using ddply

```
df.a <- ddply(df,"gamedate",function(x) c(count=nrow(x)))
df.b <- ddply(subset(df,Gls==0),"gamedate",function(x) c(count=nrow(x)))
```

and then merger df.a and df.b to get my answer. However, I am sure there must be a more
simple and elegant solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to use `summarise`:

Read the data in:

```
   dat <- read.table(textConnection("gamedate teamID Gls
  1992-08-22  CHL  3
  1992-08-22  MNU  1
  1992-08-23  ARS  0
  1992-08-23  LIV  2
  1992-08-24  MNU  0
  1992-08-25  LIV  2
  1992-08-26  ARS  0
  1992-08-26  CHL  0"),sep = "",header = TRUE)
```

and then call `ddply`:

```
ddply(dat,.(gamedate),summarise,tot = length(teamID),blanks = length(which(Gls == 0)))
    gamedate tot blanks
1 1992-08-22   2      0
2 1992-08-23   2      1
3 1992-08-24   1      1
4 1992-08-25   1      0
5 1992-08-26   2      2
```

Comment: Early bird etc. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing you are missing is wrapping your functions in a `data.frame()` call and giving them column names... and the column names are optional :)

I'm using @joran's dat data.frame as it allowed me to test my answer.

```
ddply( dat, "gamedate", function(x) data.frame( 
                                      tot = nrow( x ), 
                                      blanks = nrow( subset(x, Gls == 0 ) ) 
                                              ) 
     )
```

BTW, my funny formatting above is just to prevent it from scrolling on the screen and to help illustrate how I'm really just bringing together the functions you already created.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using simple `aggregate`. I am using joran's `dat`.

```
agg <- aggregate(cbind(1, dat$Gls==0), list(dat$gamedate), sum)
names(agg) <- c("gamedate", "games", "blanks")
agg
```

Comment: +1 for aggregate solution. Can you explain what the cbind(1, ...) is doing? Is it just acting as a "counter"?

Comment: @DWin the `cbind` adds a column of 1's which he can then sum in order to get a count of the number of rows. That way both values are summations.

Comment: hmmm. I've done things like that with tapply, so I guess it should have been more obvious to me.